# React useState does not update immediately unless refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component with a state that keep tracks of checkboxes:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function SideBar() {
  const [queryObject, setQueryObject] = useState({
    genders: [],
    availabilities: []
  });
  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;

    if (name === "male" || name === "female") {
      if (checked) {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          prevQueryObject.genders.push(name);
          return prevQueryObject;
        });
      } else {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          return prevQueryObject.genders.filter((e) => e !== name);
        });
      }
      return;
    }

    if (name === "available" || name === "not available") {
      if (checked) {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          prevQueryObject.availabilities.push(name);
          return prevQueryObject;
        });
      } else {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          return prevQueryObject.availabilities.filter((e) => e !== name);
        });
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.genders.includes("male")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="male"
      />
      <span>Male</span>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.genders.includes("female")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="female"
      />
      <span>Female</span>
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.availabilities.includes("available")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="available"
      />
      <span>Available</span>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.availabilities.includes("not available")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="not available"
      />
      <span>Not available</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

When I tried to click on the checkboxes it does not update immediately, I found that whenever I save my text file again the browser reloads and then it updates, I think the problem is in my handleChange function, is the way I'm handling the setQueryObject wrong ?

Comment: You are returning the same object. Create a new one using say spread syntax `{...prevQueryObject, genders: prevQueryObject.concat(name)}` and use `concat` because `push` mutates the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there in the approach of updating `queryObject` state . Since `queryObject` state is an object and if we try to directly modify the object
like this :-

```
    setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
      prevQueryObject.genders.push(name);
      return prevQueryObject;
    });
```

React does not recognise any change in the state since the object has the same reference so it doesn't update `DOM`. Therefore we need to create a `deep copy` of that object and set it back to the `object state` again so that change in object state is recognised and React updates the DOM.

```
    setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
      return{...prevQueryObject,genders:[...prevQueryObject.genders,name]};
    
    });
```

Full Working Code here - [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sky-oosl6q?file=/src/App.js:281-662)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Yury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) i re-wrote the code and it works

```
import { useState } from "react";

function SideBar() {
  const [queryObject, setQueryObject] = useState({
    genders: [],
    availabilities: []
  });
  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;

    if (name === "male" || name === "female") {
      if (checked) {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          return {
            ...prevQueryObject,
            genders: prevQueryObject.genders.concat(name)
          };
        });
      } else {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          return {
            ...prevQueryObject, 
            genders: prevQueryObject.genders.filter((e) => e !== name)
          }
        });
      }
      return;
    }

    if (name === "available" || name === "not available") {
      if (checked) {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          return {
            ...prevQueryObject,
            availabilities: prevQueryObject.availabilities.concat(name)
          };
        });
      } else {
        setQueryObject((prevQueryObject) => {
          return {
            ...prevQueryObject,
            availabilities: prevQueryObject.availabilities.filter(
              (e) => e !== name
            )
          };
        });
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.genders.includes("male")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="male"
      />
      <span>Male</span>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.genders.includes("female")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="female"
      />
      <span>Female</span>
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.availabilities.includes("available")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="available"
      />
      <span>Available</span>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={queryObject.availabilities.includes("not available")}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="not available"
      />
      <span>Not available</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

Comment: would be great if you can describe what your code is doing hee.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).